# Inheritance in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, inheritance, orm

I would like to implement inheritance in Hibernate.

I created ObjectClass object:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ObjectClass {
    private id;

}
```

and CodeTable object that inhertance Object class:

```
@Entity
@ForeignKey(name = "id")
@Table(name = "code_table")
public class CodeTable extends  ObjectClass{
    private String description;
}
```

in the database

object table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `object` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 )
```

code_table table is:

-

```
CREATE TABLE `code_table` (
  `id` bigint(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `description` varchar(45) character set latin1 default NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
   KEY `FK_object` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_object` FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `object` (`id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
 )
```

I wrote the following code to retreive data from codeTable:

```
 @SuppressWarnings( "unchecked" )
    @Transactional( readOnly = true, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED )
    public Collection<CodeTable> findAll() {
        Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();

        return 
            session.createCriteria( persistentClass 
                    ).setResultTransformer( Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY
                            ).list();
    }
```

I gets empty list although there is one record in codetable table.

When I write the following SQL in my database:

```
SELECT * FROM `code_table`
```

I get:
id= 1,
description = company.

What went wrong in my Hibernate definition? How can I retrieve the object?

**EDITED**:
My hibernate.cfg.xml file looks like this:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
           <mapping class="com.mycompany.model.CodeTable" />
           <mapping class="com.mycompany.model.ObjectClass" />
        </session-factory>  
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Comment: If you're only going to use ObjectClass to hold the id, I think it's better if you don't have a separate table for it (especially since you already have the id column in your child classes). Instead only use it as a separate class in Java, and have each child class have it's own table with the id column referring to the id property inherited from ObjectClass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mappings and table structure are (roughly) correct for a JOINED inheritance strategy and I cannot reproduce your problem.

I use the following mappings (which are basically the one you provided):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class ObjectClass {
    @Id @GeneratedValue 
    private Long id;

    public ObjectClass() { }

    public Long getId() { return id; }
    public void setId(Long id) { this.id = id; }
}
```

And

```
@Entity
@ForeignKey(name = "id")
@Table(name = "code_table")
public class CodeTable extends  ObjectClass{
    private String description;

    public CodeTable() { }

    public String getDescription() { return description; }
    public void setDescription(String description) { 
        this.description = description; 
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
    return "CodeTable [getDescription()=" + getDescription() + ", getId()="
            + getId() + "]";
    }
}
```

The following tables:

```
create table code_table (
    description varchar(255),
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

create table object (
    id bigint not null,
    primary key (id)
)

alter table code_table 
    add constraint id 
    foreign key (id) 
    references object
```

And the following parent/child records:

```
insert into object values (1);
insert into code_table(id, description) values (1, 'foo');
```

And running your criteria query:

```
session.createCriteria(CodeTable.class)
    .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
    .list();
```

Returns:

```
CodeTable [getDescription()=foo, getId()=1]
```

Everything works as expected.

#### References

- JPA 1.0 Specification

  - 2.1.10 Inheritance Mapping Strategies
- Hibernate Annotations Reference Guide

  - [2.2.4. Mapping inheritance](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e1168)

Comment: you wrote "(roughly) correct" what is not correct about her implementation?

Comment: @Odelya: Things like no Java type for the `id`, no mandatory `Id` annotation (but the inheritance part itself is correct).

Comment: Tanks Pascal,
My mistake was in the annotation: I defined the “catalog” for certain database and connected to a different one… :(

Comment: @Rivki: Stuff happens :) Glad it's fixed though.

Answer (score 1):

How does your mapping looks like ?

Have you read this section in the Hibernate doc ?
[Inheritance mapping in Hibernate](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/inheritance.html)

As you can read in the link I provided above, your mapping is not correct.  You have to let Hibernate know that the code_table class inherits  from the object class, and you 'll have to let Hibernate know how this link exists in the database.

Comment: How should I change my mapping in hibernate.cfg.xml?

Comment: Rivki, please read the document that I refer to.  All the information that you're looking for, is in there.  There are some design decisions that you'll have to make.

Comment: She uses annotation! why does she need to map it in a different file?
See them above the object declaration..

Comment: Hi Frederik, 

The  offered way will works with an old version of Heibernate,
Heibernate 3 dones't need mapping for the tables, it uses Heibernate  annotations instead.
my questions is how to define Heibernate  annotations for a sub class??

10X